ggplot's geom_boxplot(outlier.size = NA, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) Outlier not ommitted and Position Dodge does not work
I am working on a data visualization in R Shiny where I aim to display the spread of avg_speed for each hour of the day using boxplots. My goal is to represent each road as a separate boxplot within the same graph, displayed side by side for each hour.
For example, if the time range is 1 AM to 2 AM and the user selects three roads, the graph should show three distinct boxplots (one for each road) side by side, all grouped under the 1 AM to 2 AM label. However, in my current implementation, the boxplots are overlapping, which affects the clarity of the visualization.
Even though, I am including outlier.size = NA, outliers are still visible.
The code is as follows:
output$boxplot <- renderPlotly({
  p <- ggplot(aggregated_data, aes(x = time_by_hour, y = avg_speed, fill = RoadName.x)) + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.size = NA, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
    labs(
      title = "Distribution of average speed (in mph) by each hour (Hover over the boxplots to know more info)",
      subtitle = "Hover over the boxplots to know more info",
      x = "Time by Hour",
      y = "Average Speed (mph)",
      legend = "Road") +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +  
    theme(
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),        
      panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "#f2f0ef"),   
      panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "#f2f0ef"),
      plot.title = element_text(size = 12),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(size = font_size_for_boxplot),          
      axis.title.x = element_text(size = font_size_for_boxplot),  
      axis.title.y = element_text(size = font_size_for_boxplot),          
      axis.text.x = element_text(size = font_size_for_boxplot) ,     
      axis.text.y = element_text(size = font_size_for_boxplot) ,
      legend.position = "right",                                     
      legend.text = element_text(size = 8),                          
      legend.title = element_text(size = 8),                            
    ) 
  # Add hover information
  ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("time_by_hour", "avg_speed", "RoadName.x")) #, "RoadName.x"
})

Here are the specific requirements:

The x-axis should display the time range (hour of the day), and
boxplots should be grouped under each hour.
For each hour, multiple boxplots (one for each selected road) should
appear side by side.
Facets are not preferred as I want all roads to appear in the same
graph.
Outliers should not be visualized to maintain a cleaner appearance.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to modify the code to achieve this layout effectively.
The dput(aggregated_data):
structure(list(
    RoadName.x = c("North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", "North Craycroft Road", 
    "North Craycroft Road"), avg_speed = c(33.6666666666667, 
    34, 34, 34, 34, 33.3333333333333, 34.3333333333333, 34, 34, 
    34, 34, 34, 34.3333333333333, 34.3333333333333, 34.3333333333333, 
    35.3333333333333, 34.6666666666667, 34, 33, 33.6666666666667, 
    31.6666666666667, 31.3333333333333, 31, 31, 31, 32.6666666666667, 
    33.6666666666667, 34.3333333333333, 35, 35, 35.6666666666667, 
    35.6666666666667, 34, 34.3333333333333, 34.6666666666667, 
    35.3333333333333, 35, 35, 34.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
    32.6666666666667, 31.3333333333333, 31.3333333333333, 31.3333333333333, 
    31.6666666666667), time_by_hour = c("14", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
    "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
    "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", 
    "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", 
    "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15"
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -45L))

The current Output is attached as a screenshot 

Try x = factor(time_by_hour). Also please include output of dput(head(aggregated_data, 20)) instead of print output, so we can reproduce your code at least with a part of the data.

Try running with outlier.shape = NA (not outlier.size) and rendering as a regular ggplot, not as renderPlotly. I think the plot will work. I don't know how to fix the rendering to plotly.

To fix the issue with dodging use ggplotly() %>%> layout(boxmode = "group"). See Keeping dodge position in boxplot passed to plotly. To not display the outliers use geom_boxplot(outliers = FALSE, ...)(requires ggplot2 >= 3.5.0)

Thank you @stefan Now the boxplots are displayed side-by-side. However, the outliers still show up in the visualization. Also, the ggplot2 version currently installed in my R environment is 3.5.1

Hm. I tried with ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(vs))) + geom_boxplot(outliers = FALSE, position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)); ggplotly() |> layout(boxmode = "group"). Setting outliers=TRUE shows the outliers but using outliers = FALSE omits them.

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("time_by_hour", "avg_speed", "RoadName.x")) %>%             layout(boxmode = "group",                    legend = list(orientation = "h", y = -0.3))
I am also running this code to show tooltip on hover. If this line is included, then the outlier is included in the boxplot visual even if I set outliers = FALSE @stefan

I have edited the question such that it shows dput(aggregated_data) for sample data instead of head() @stefan

Interesting. Looks like only some outliers get dropped when we set outliers=FALSE. I think this is limitation of (gg)plotly. But you can fix that by manipulating the plotly object, e.g. ggp <- ggplotly(...); for (i in seq_along(ggp$x$data)) { ggp$x$data[[i]]$marker$opacity = 0 }; ggp. See Remove outliers from a ggplotly() boxplot.

That worked. Thanks! @stefan
